# How to retrieve data of a Foreign key in django model using a single call?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have 2 classes:

```
class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
     location = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, null=True, related_name="book")
    no_of_pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

I want to be able to access the Author's data from Book using a single call.
Eg:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(genre="fiction")
for book in books:
    print book.author.name, book.author.location
```

As I understand, this has to hit db several times.  Is there a way to obtain the data of author using a single call?

Comment: It's only hitting the DB several times because you're in a for loop. You filtered out several books thus you have several authors to iterate over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use select_related.

```
books = Book.objects.filter(genre="fiction").select_related("author")
```

This will fetch the db only one time and auto load the `author` model inside the `book`.